# Why link on image from Google/Microsofot Drive is not working in html as src img? Or how to make it work?

Tags: html

I want to use images stored online like at my Google or Microsoft drive (or any other online storage) as links at a my website. 
How to make it working? I tried to insert links like this. 
Only the link from w3schools was working: (but if enter in browser all 3 links are working). Whatever I tried I cannot generate links in  Google or Microsoft drive that will work as image links. Is it not possible there? If so what is alternative to generate linkable image resources?

```html
<!--not working links from google and microsoft drives:-->
<p>
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ofVPo7Ni4YQQXb-tSrmxBjcXsJiiLnwz/view?usp=sharing" alt="image test">
</p>
<p>
  <img src="https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ampo_wgRsj_Tg_NU8t_oA2t0Ph4rTw" alt="image test">
</p>
<!--working link:-->
<p>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="image test">
</p>
```

Comment: The first two are not links for an image, they are links for a **website**.

Comment: Check if your google drive link is set to share to "Public" Howto: https://www.wonderplugin.com/online-tools/google-drive-direct-link-generator/

Comment: Aha. In Google/Microsoft drive I tried to get links to an image: and it generated those links. Do you know or how to generate link to image from Google/Microsoft drive? is it possible?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do as in "Howto" but it gives only those not working links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you're giving to your `src` isnt a direct link to a picture. It is a link to a website (in this case, your shared file on Drive) which contains the image. The actual image address you need to feed the `src` is diffrent. To find it, right click the picture and press "Copy image address".

Comment: @NikolayZ Keep in mind that the image URL you get may or may not be static, and you may be better off hosting images at a different provider specifically designed for static images. E.g. Imgur

Comment: Thank you. In Google/Microsoft drive I tried to get links to an image even if I right clicked: and it generated those links. Do you know or how to generate link to image from Google/Microsoft drive? is it possible? If it is not possible what alternative to Google/Microsoft drive can you advice which will allow image link generation?

Comment: @Robert S.Thank you. Unfortunately right click on the picture does not make it to generate any different from this not working link.

Answer (score 0):

You shall give the URL to the image and not the site.
For example - `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YN9L7WKpVDA3MFVQSP5NNPHaBkALPYiYrK-fdisD4ViXbAiKfimwpO9i00ts7HZqiSseEE-ZilC2yqElVJm9=w3360-h1744-rw`
See this [pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/XZmNze)

Answer (score 0):

I accept Robert S answer as correct answer to my question for why part. I also found a solution which helped me: it worked well in AWS S3 bucket. I just uploaded images there and it gives the true images links. Important in AWS it need to allow "public access" to resource.